# Why do some MySQL threads never die?

Tags: php, mysql, iis

I'm running a PHP web app on IIS with a MySQL back end.

My database gets quite a bit of traffic during peak times (up to 5,000 selects per second) and sometimes I run into performance issues so I'm trying to track that down and eliminate the problem.

My CPU, Ram, Disk, Network are all fine and well below capacity, but I've noticed that sometimes there are many idle threads hanging around when things get bogged down and if I manually kill those threads performance comes back up.

[image: Threads]

In this example there are not a huge amount of idle threads but you can see that there are a couple that have been alive for over 500 seconds.  Sometimes I see many threads alive for over 500 seconds and I don't know why they don't kill themselves.

The following are my connection values

[image: Connections]

I have my max connections on this server set to 1500, so I know I'm not running into that limit.  Not sure if this is relevant but my innodb_thread_concurrency is set to 66.

And the following are my timeout settings for mysql

[image]

Obviously server config is not my thing.  I am but a lowly developer trying to make a living in this world.  My question is, could these long running idle threads be causing a bottle neck on my server and slowing things down?  And if so, what are the settings that I should be looking at and tweaking to make sure my server is properly handling the load?

Comment: Why would idle threads impact performance? In my experience these only use a bit of memory and a filehandle or two.

Comment: Are you sure to **close** the connection, if you don't wan't this anymore? Looks like other clients had connected but never disconnected. If you using applications there never die, the connection will be opened, even if the application has no more "activity"...

Comment: I'm closing connections in my code as far as I know but my application has literally tens of thousands of pages of code so it's entirely possible that some of my code is not closing the connection.  However, my understanding is that connections should be closed automatically anyway after a certain amount of time.  Why does it seem to happen for some threads but not for others?

Comment: @tadman, I'm not sure why or how these idle threads are impacting performance but every indication is that they are.  They're not using up any cpu or ram, so that's not an issue but I do notice high latency on some of my pages when there are lots of idle threads so it seems to be bottle necking somehow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out the problem was a parameter I had added to the my.ini file.  open-files-limit = 4096.

It was recommended that I add this parameter if I increased the size of the table_cache from 300 to 2000.  Turns out this was bad advice.  As soon as I commented out open-files-limit = 4096 all my problems went away.  Threads started dying and they reduced from a range of 300 to 500 idle threads down to below 20 idle threads.